# Worklight 6.2 - Mobile Browser Simulator Not Rendering Application Correctly

Tags: templates, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am working with Worklight 6.2 Enterprise Edition along with Dojo and dojox/app. I have been experiencing some very strange behaviour with the MBS.

I have some Dojo templates that are used to create widgets.

Each time I load the MBS the view is loaded but often the widgets instantiated from the templates are not being loaded correctly and I am receiving an error from Dojo about an "Invalid Template". Periodically everything loads fine.

When I look under the Network tab in Chrome's Developer Tools and look at the response from the server for one of the broken templates what I see is a portion of code from other parts of the HTML. For example, the template should simply be a small HTML file containing code for an input field and a label but the browser received sections of HTML from completely unrelated sections of the app (for example, the HTML for other templates).

Each time I do a refresh I receive a different result for the same file which may contain superfluous code, too little code, or be correct.

I am not able to recreate this behaviour on device which leads me to believe there is something wrong with the Worklight development server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been identified as a defect and was recently resolved.

The intention is to have the fix publically available from IBM Fix Central as well as the Eclipse Marketplace, soon (late July, 2014).
I suggest to check back by the end of the month and re-download & install the Worklight Studio plug-in at that time to verify your issue was indeed resolved.

IBM customers can see the APAR page at: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1PI21516

If you opened a PMR for this issue, a fix will be provided there as well.

Comment: i have this problem too.. preview common resources at worklight shows blank! i cannot find a way to fix it through the link that you provided. can you explain the steps a little more?

Comment: Get a new Eclipse, install the latest Studio plug-in (dated August 18th).

Comment: i have eclipse 4.3 kepler sr2 package and the latest version of the worklight studio plugin..the latest eclipse 4.4 luna doesn't open on Debian 7.6 due to an eclipse bug. any ideas?